# Passing dispatch to typed CreatedAsyncThunk via thunkApi config parameter is causing error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I've created a typed `AsyncThunk` following the instructions from the [redux-toolkit docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#createasyncthunk). It consists in a method to get data from an API, without any filters and return as a typed array. The code in this `AsyncThunk` also calls a function to show the loading progress of data and I'm trying to use the ThunkApi config to get a reference to dispatch and call this function.

I'm doing this way:

deviceOperations.ts

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { AppDispatch } from 'src/store';
import { loaderActions } from '../../../features/loader/redux';
import deviceManager from '../deviceManager';

export const getAllDevices = createAsyncThunk<
  Device[],
  {
    dispatch: AppDispatch;
  }
>('device/GET_ALL_DEVICES', async (thunkApi) => {
  thunkApi.dispatch(loaderActions.start('getAllDevices'));
  try {
    const devices = await deviceManager.getAllDevices();
    return { ...devices };
  } finally {
    thunkApi.dispatch(loaderActions.stop('getAllDevices'));
  }
});
```

DevicePage.tsx

```
const DevicePage = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const { push } = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(deviceOperations.getAllDevices());
  }, [dispatch]);
};
```

The line `dispatch(deviceOperations.getAllDevices());` is causing the error `Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554) typings.d.ts(302, 701): An argument for 'arg' was not provided.`.

What is wrong with this function?

Answer (score 1):

The `AsyncThunkPayloadCreator` expects you to declare at least one argument I believe. In the example in the doc it's userId of type number for example.

In your case, you don't want to pass an arg, but you still have to declare a void argument. Just modify your `getAllDevices` function declaration to this:

```js
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { AppDispatch } from 'src/store';
import { loaderActions } from '../../../features/loader/redux';
import deviceManager from '../deviceManager';

// notice the empty arg _. You could type it with `void`
export const getAllDevices = createAsyncThunk('device/GET_ALL_DEVICES', async (_, thunkApi) => {
  thunkApi.dispatch(loaderActions.start('getAllDevices'));
  try {
    const devices = await deviceManager.getAllDevices();
    return { ...devices };
  } finally {
    thunkApi.dispatch(loaderActions.stop('getAllDevices'));
  }
});
```